# Worklight Analytics Context Root Not found

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-analytics

I was following this guide to add the analytics context root at: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/monitor/t_installing_op_analytics_liberty.html

But I am getting context root not found.

Part of my error logs:

```
[2/16/15 8:44:15:327 EST] 0000005f com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for application key default_host/analytics
[2/16/15 8:44:15:369 EST] 0000005f com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               W SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/data/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[data:[/data/*]], application-->analytics.
[2/16/15 8:44:15:388 EST] 0000005f com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.wink.providers.abdera.AbderaAtomFeedProvider (initialization failure) com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.VirtualHost startWebApp" at ffdc_15.02.16_08.44.15.0.log
[2/16/15 8:44:30:995 EST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for application key default_host/analytics
[2/16/15 8:44:31:032 EST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               W SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/data/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[data:[/data/*]], application-->analytics.
[2/16/15 8:45:36:135 EST] 0000001d com.ibm.puremeap.util.android.AAPT                           I findAAPT: Could not find aapt. Please set property android.aapt or android.aapt.dir.
[2/16/15 8:49:51:147 EST] 00000093 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for application key default_host/analytics
[2/16/15 8:49:51:178 EST] 00000093 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               W SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/data/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[data:[/data/*]], application-->analytics.
[2/16/15 8:52:17:431 EST] 00000077 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for application key default_host/analytics
[2/16/15 8:52:17:467 EST] 00000077 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               W SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/data/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[data:[/data/*]], application-->analytics.
[2/16/15 8:52:44:771 EST] 00000021 .ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.WebAppSecurityCollaboratorImpl A CWWKS9104A: Authorization failed for user demo while invoking worklightadmin on /. The user is not granted access to any of the required roles: [worklightadmin, worklightmonitor, worklightoperator, worklightdeployer]
```

Another log:

```
[2/16/15 9:45:15:769 EST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for application key default_host/analytics
[2/16/15 9:45:15:801 EST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               W SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/data/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[data:[/data/*]], application-->analytics.
[2/16/15 9:45:15:822 EST] 00000018 com.ibm.ws.logging.internal.impl.IncidentImpl                I FFDC1015I: An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.wink.providers.abdera.AbderaAtomFeedProvider (initialization failure) com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.VirtualHost startWebApp" at ffdc_15.02.16_09.45.15.0.log
[2/16/15 9:45:19:308 EST] 0000001d com.ibm.ws.session.WASSessionCore                            I SESN0175I: An existing session context will be used for application key default_host/analytics
[2/16/15 9:45:19:343 EST] 0000001d com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               W SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/data/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[data:[/data/*]], application-->analytics.
worklnew:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/defaultServer/logs #
```

Server.xml:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5afsr3jfmv0h7y/serverxmlforpmr.xml?dl=0

Comment: Can  you try changing the classloader policy for the analytics application from "parentLast" to "parentFirst", and let us know if that resolves the problem?

Comment: Hi Pat, I posted the new error. Same issue. Is it possible I have a bad war file? I had an issue with a war file on this server before.  I needed an updated one.

Comment: If this helps, I added this to my worklight.proerties file -- wl.analytics.url=http://myserverurl/analytics/data

Comment: Can you provide as much information as you can from your server.xml file? In particular, which Liberty features you added?

Comment: Server.xml is in dropbox.

Comment: Analytics works if I create another server and use a different port. Any ideas on linking itA?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error that occurred in the GM version of 6.2.0. Do you have the exact version of Worklight you're using? Can you try upgrading to the latest fixpack or iFix available and seeing if that resolves the issue?

Comment: According to my appcenterconsole I am at productVersion 6.2.0.01-20141013-1735

Comment: I am not getting any errors in my log files but  I get context root not found

Comment: I see the analytics console server but on port 8080, I had made a second server. my worklight.properties has entries commented out.

Comment: Hi Idan, so I got the worklight analytics console to work by deleting the 2 files as suggested in the APAR. I can now see the console on my server. However, I don't see any application data. Is there anyway to confirm that it is working right? Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: I recommend setting the following worklight property: wl.analytics.queue.size=1. This will allow you to see data sent immediately.